# Daggerspell guardians - anyone seen/created stats for (3.5) "The emerald knives of seven truths"

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

In the 'Complete Adventurer' the Daggerspell Guardians are seeking a pair of daggers  called the emerald knives of seven truths.

> "Lore of the Guild: Many of the greatest treasures of the Daggerspell Guardians are daggers of great power. Two of the most treasured of these daggers, *the emerald knives of seven truths*, were lost years ago by a daggerspell shaper who fell in battle against a powerful vampire named Malkan Ry-Ul. Both the knives and the vampire have been missing for many years, but recently travelers from the east have reported that a great city there is haunted by a killer who leaves strange green cuts on the bodies of his victims - a signature side effect of the magic of the emerald knives".

Has anyone seen or created (or have any advice) for their stats please?

For info: I'm playing a daggerspell shaper searching for them.

To qualify to become one a character must fulfill all the following criteria:

*Alignment: Any nonevil.

Skills: Concentration 8 ranks.

Feats: Weapon Focus (dagger), Two-Weapon Fighting.

Special: Wild shape class feature.

Special: Either sneak attack +1d6 or skirmish +1d6.*

This makes me wonder if the daggers either do some of these things (as they may have inspired the creation of said group in the first place)?!

Comment: Are you looking for generic stats for these? Or are you looking for setting-specific stats? Much of 3.5 was designed to highlight the Greyhawk campaign setting. As such, it may be appropriate to look at Greyhawk druidic lore to determine the function of the knives. For that, Beory, the Oerth Mother, is a good source of druidic lore. Her adherents are often contemplative. I could easily see the "seven truths" having something to do with that faith.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Our game is in the FR & at this point we are just looking for *any* ideas. I'll have a look at Beory. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Google can find exactly three (3) pages for the query `"emerald knives of seven truths"`:

1. This question.
2. A probably-copyright-infringing copy of *Complete Adventurer*’s description for the daggerspell guardian.
3. A thread on a web forum associated with “Baldur’s Gate: The Sword Coast Chronicles,” a “persistent-world” server for *Neverwinter Nights 2*, which is a computer game based on D&D 3.5e’s rules and set in the Forgotten Realms. The forum requires an account to view posts, so I created one just to see if someone was talking about some actual items called the *emerald knives of seven truths*. Alas, the use of the phrase is simply because someone linked to and quoted from the description at link 2 in response to someone asking how to roleplay a daggerspell mage. Based on responses, it appears the game does not include that description itself, nor were the players there familiar with the class’s origins in *Complete Adventurer*.

(Google notes some results were omitted for being very similar to these—if you include those, you get the Recent Questions page, the Active Questions page, and so on, for this site, since this question’s title appears on each of those pages. You don’t get any new results.)

These appear to be literally the only instances of that exact phrase on the entire Internet. That **strongly** suggests that no *emerald knives of seven truths* have ever been statted up, since if they were, people would probably talk about it. Rather, they were most likely a one-off mention found only in that paragraph of *Complete Adventurer*, meant to maybe be inspiration to a DM looking to flesh out the history of the daggerspell guardians. A potential plot hook that a DM could run with if they wanted. Given the lack of search results, if any DM has, they don’t seem to have posted on the Internet about it. This is unsurprising, as D&D 3.5e has a **lot** of background details that exist only as similar off-hand mentions like this, and few of them garner a lot of attention.

Comment: Great minds think alike... Tried the same & also signed up to the same site. Thx

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant purely as an example. Feel free to change anything you want about it.

Since you are playing in the FR, you could look into the [Emerald Enclave](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=fr/pg20011128x). They appear to avoid good or evil, and as such, a daggerspell shaper may be a former member who decided they wished to do good in the world. The Seven Truths could then be mixed with tenets of their old order, along with abilities that would benefit a protector of nature. It may fit that these knives, originally weapons of the Enclave, were modified once the druid became a Daggerspell Shaper. I would look for five or six truths of the Emerald Enclave along with one or two reasons why the original member left the order to become a Daggerspell Shaper.

1. One can see further from the top of the mountain than the heart of the forest.
2. War burns faster than a tree grows.
3. One cannot push a tree in any direction, but a hole in the forest canopy urges it towards the sky.
4. Nature can be wild, untamed, and self-destructive, but it is still nature and must be honored and protected.
5. While spoken truths spread knowledge, they also invite dangers. A silent forest is still a forest, but no hunters trample through.
6. Pestilence and disease spread ruin like wildfire. A rapid reaction can end the rot before it begins.
7. The wilderness is ever changing, and while its bounty may change over time, it remains, as always, the greatest of boons to the world.

The first five of these "seven truths", I generated from the four articles linked in the Emerald Enclave article above. The sixth is a passing reference to Sudden Strike, Sneak Attack, or Skirmish. The last is a passing reference to a good alignment.

Still, these truths may help guide the stats for the knives:

Each knife individually is a +2 flaming dagger (the flame burns green, and when active, causes green burn marks on its victim).

Each dagger has three light settings: Not active (off), light in a 10-foot radius (as a first level spell), or magical darkness in a 10-foot radius (as a first level spell). If the two are both activated to the same setting, the radius extends an additional 10 feet (as a second level spell), but if they are set to opposite settings, they cancel each other out, as if neither is activated at all.

Similarly, each dagger has two sound-based effects: Not active (off), silence in a 10-foot radius (as a first level spell). If both are activated, the area of silence extends to 20 feet as a second level spell.

When together, the two knives possess additional abilities:

- Once per day, the wielder can cast *Clairaudience/Clairvoyance* as a spell-like ability.
- At will, *Remove disease*
- When casting a healing spell through the dagger, you may add the weapon's damage (1d4+2) as a bonus to the healing.

Perhaps wielding the two daggers actually turns them into intelligent items, and the daggers have managed to overcome the will of the vampire, forcing it to become a protector of nature.

Comment: Love the ideas!! Thx for the suggestions!!

Comment: @Obi1 I'm glad you like it. When your group eventually decides on stats, I'd love to see what you go with.

Comment: thx. Will do but  may have to look in to creating legacy weapons first

Comment: If they are legacy weapons, does that mean the vampire went out of its way to satisfy the legacy rituals meant to unlock the daggers so that it could be a protector of nature? That seems... odd...

Comment: Agreed! Can't imagine that... The thing is our ref (to the best of my knowledge has only been getting a few years) may not want to dedicate a lot of time in to creating stats for the daggers ... So I may have to propose some ideas? Maybe to help get his creative juices flowing. Which makes me think "legacy"

Comment: Also... He could have been a blighter/evil druid prior to being a vampire..?! Otherwise why would he keep them anyway..!?